# "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid." In VB

Tags: vb.net

When I try to run the program to calculate payment and total intrest I get "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid."

What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim P As Double
Dim R As Double
Dim N As Double
Dim Payment As Double
Dim totalInterest As Double

Private Sub btnAnalyze_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAnalyze.Click

P = CDbl(txtAmount.Text)
N = CDbl(txtDuration.Text)
R = CDbl(txtInterestRate.Text)

Payment = (P * R) / (1 - (1 + R) ^ (-N))
totalInterest = (N * Payment) - P

Payment = CDbl(txtPayment.Text)
totalInterest = CDbl(txtInterest.Text)

If P < 0 Then
MessageBox.Show("Please enter in loan amount")

End If

If R <= 0 Then
MessageBox.Show("Please enter in loan amount")

End If

If N <= 0 Then
MessageBox.Show("Please enter in loan amount")

End If


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: one of the text boxes is empty

Comment: You should put a break point at the begining of the function and look at the value inside the 5 textbox. I'm pretty sure one of them is empty. Double.TryParse si the best option for converting strings to double since it will tell you if the conversion was done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your `TextBox` items has not been filled in.

As such, when you use `CDbl`, such as `P = CDbl(txtAmount.Text)`, if the `TextBox` is empty, it will cause this error.

A better option would be to use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) instead of `CDbl`, as it will allow you to raise a proper message:

```
Private Sub btnAnalyze_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAnalyze.Click

If Not Double.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, P) Then
     MessageBox.Show("Please correct the loan amount")
     Exit Sub
End If

' Do the same for all other CDbl checks
```

Comment: still give mes the conversion error with the the statement: Payment = CDbl(txtPayment.Text)

Comment: @SadieStokes What line is giving the error?  Can you show your **new** version of the code?  Note that EVERY CDbl needs replacemetn for this to work...

Comment: Here is the error in bold: `Dim TotalInterest As Double
    Dim Payment As Double
    Dim P As Long
    Dim R As Double
    Dim N As Integer

    Private Sub btnAnalyze_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAnalyze.Click

       Payment = (P * R) / (1 - (1 + R) ^ (-N))
        totalInterest = (N * Payment) - P

        **Payment = CDbl(txtPayment.Text)**
        totalInterest = CDbl(txtInterest.Text)

        If Not Double.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, P) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter in loan amount")
        End If`

Comment: sorry about the paragraph form, I don't know how to make it to view as code

Comment: @SadieStokes You need to do the same thing above with Payment and totalInterest.  Use the "Double.TryParse" method for everything pulling from a TextBox (instead of CDbl)

Comment: @SadieStokes Your code, as shown, is still using CDbl.  Edit your question, and put the current version at teh end, and I can help you figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I know this original question is old, but it's trending on Google.

Everyone has been right, to a degree, so far..  The CDbl function you were attempting doesn't handle blanks very well (it blows up).  In some cases (mine specifically) TryParse isn't an option (see below for 'why' along with true solution)

IF, however, you are expecting numbers in the data, and receiving an error isn't possible (long story short, that is my context) then you HAVE to use CDbl, since there isn't another conversion method that can be used in a single expression (again, my context).

In my case, since i wasn't able to declare variables, i found an elegant solution this problem.  I did it with a concatenator, in my case (I'm using vb.net ) it was `CDbl("0" + txtAmount.Text)` where P is the original data your testing for, and then R and N, etc.

This does what `Val()` used to do, by defaulting a leading zero, you have not changed any of the data within the variable, but have only solved blanks.  There are more wholistic solutions, but I couldn't utilize those since I only had access to "one-liners" so-to-speak

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it is simply because you want:

```
txtPayment.Text = CStr(Payment)
txtInterest.Text = CStr(totalInterest)
```

instead of

```
Payment = CDbl(txtPayment.Text)
totalInterest = CDbl(txtInterest.Text)
```

Comment: no it's not possible to do that in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: If the `.Text` property is read-only with the control you're using, there must be a property, or method, allowing you to set what is displayed. My main point is that, as it stands, you're throwing away the calculated `Payment` and `totalInterest` from the two lines previous to the ones I'm suggesting to change.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of CDbl(),use Val() of function it converts the string into 0 default,if the text box is empty. Then runtime error may not come..

Comment: I think Val is deprecated.

Comment: Val never supported international swapping of commas and periods, so it had to be rewritten anyways