# Why I get this error in Vb.net while connecting mysql “Conversion from string to type ‘Double’ is not valid”?

Tags: vb.net, mysql-connector

I tried the equation separately. It worked. But after I joined, i got the error of conversion. My aim is to get MySql data to the vb.net So I can check some values and develop the project. I have to finish the project within one week and I don’t know how to finish this. If this seems easy please forgive me.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form3
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    Dim command As MySqlCommand
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim Da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'To check whether the date is same
        TextBox1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString(("MM/dd/yyyy"))

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;password=1234;database=attendance"
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        Try
            ds.Clear()
            conn.Open()
            'Checking Subject Now
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("select Subject_Name from dateverification", conn)
            Da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Da.Fill(ds, "dateverification")
            TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)

            'Checking Todays Date
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("select Today_Date from dateverification", conn)
            Da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Da.Fill(ds, "dateverification")
            Label1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)

            'Checking Count1
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("select Count1 from dateverification", conn)
            Da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Da.Fill(ds, "dateverification")
            Label2.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)

            'Checking Count2
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("select Count2 from dateverification", conn)
            Da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Da.Fill(ds, "dateverification")
            Label3.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)

            'If the days are Different, Total days will be counted and Date will be updated
            If Label1.Text <> TextBox1.Text Then
                Label1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString(("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                Label2.Text = Label2.Text + 1
                Dim query1 As String
                query1 = "UPDATE attendance.dateverification SET Today_Date = '" & Label1.Text & "' , Count1 = '" & Label2.Text & "' WHERE Subject_Name = '" & TextBox3.Text & "'; "
                command = New MySqlCommand(query1, conn)
                reader = command.ExecuteReader
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome to New Day")

            Else
            'If the date are equal, then the number of counts which register wasopen in same day will be increased
                Label3.Text = Label3.Text + 1
                Dim query1 As String
                query1 = "UPDATE attendance.dateverification SET Count2 = '" & Label3.Text & "' WHERE Subject_Name = '" & TextBox3.Text & "'; "
                command = New MySqlCommand(query1, conn)
                reader = command.ExecuteReader
                MessageBox.Show("You are still on the same day")

            End If

            Dim query As String
            query = "UPDATE attendance.dateverification SET Subject_selected = '" & TextBox3.Text & "' WHERE Subject_Name = '" & TextBox3.Text & "'; "
            command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
            reader = command.ExecuteReader
            conn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()

        End Try
```

Comment: Are you able to identify which part is returning the error msg? Is it from VB.net or from MySQL? Also you may refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632245/conversion-from-string-to-type-double-is-not-valid-in-vb) if it's relatable to your situation

Comment: I check it. But unfortunately I found no error even in MySql. I didn’t enter any extra code in sql rather than creating the tables. So I think the error is in here. I tryied this question and still I can’t find a thing. My head is going to get blast with the time limit. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Use the debugger. That's why you have an IDE. When the exception is thrown, the debugger will tell you exactly what line it was thrown on. You can then examine that line and see what it is doing and where you are expecting a `Double` and using a `String`. If you can't identify it there and then, use the debugger more. Set a breakpoint and run the project again and then examine the state at each line leading up to where the exception is thrown.

Comment: I would also suggest that you turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties and also in the IDE options, so it is always `On` by default in the future. An example of places where this exception might be throw is here: `Label2.Text = Label2.Text + 1`. There you are adding a `String` and an `Integer`, which is nonsensical. You are relying on one of those values being implicitly converted to the other type, which is always fraught. What happens if that `String` is empty? Pay attention to your data types and ALWAYS perform casts and conversions explicitly after appropriate validation.

Comment: Apart from that, you should not be using a `Label` in a calculation anyway. `Labels` are for display, not storage. If a `Label` is supposed to display a number then declare a numeric variable and store the number there. If you need to change the number, change the variable first and then display the new value in the `Label`. You can't possibly use an invalid `String` in that case.

Comment: Holy sql injection issue, Batman!

Comment: Than you for the comment jmcilhinney. I will recheck it. I never thought that much. Our deploma didnt teach this much even. But I tryied to solve things. Thank you for your help. I will try it again.

Comment: If you temporarily get rid of the `Try...Catch...Finally....End Try` code your code will break on the line causing the error.

Comment: I got the answer. Thank you Joel.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the error is because this code is not always legal:

```
Label3.Text = Label3.Text + 1
```

`Label3.Text` is a string. Depending on compiler options, you can't just expect the compiler to convert it to a number for you. *Those options are there to help you, and you should use them.*

Moving on.

Not 100% sure on MySql, but in Sql Server for sure you could do all this as one connection command job in the database. This will perform better, and helped me *greatly* simplify the code.

Pay special attention to how I used parameters. It's **NEVER** okay to use string concatenation to put parameter values into a query. This is too important even for learning or proof of concept code.

```vb
Option Strict On
Option Infer On

Imports System
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form3

    'Don't try to keep the connection/command objects at the form level!
    'Do keep the connection string here:
    Private ConnectionString As String = "server=localhost;user=root;password=1234;database=attendance"

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim conn As SqlConnection

        'I put two statements in one command string,
        ' and the CASE expressions let me get all of the updates into one statement
        Dim sql As String = 
"UPDATE attendance.dateverification 
    SET Count1 = CASE WHEN Today_Date <> current_date THEN Count1 + 1 ELSE Count1 END,
        Count2 = CASE WHEN Today_Date = current_date THEN Count2 + 1 ELSE Count2 END,   
        Today_Date = current_date,
        Subject_selected = @subject 
WHERE Subject_Name = @subject;

SELECT Subject_Name, Today_Date, Count1, Count2 
FROM dateverification"
' Also note: this string could be a constant if we wanted to!

        Try
            conn = New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
            'Use actual type and length here
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@subject", MySqlDbType.VarString, 50).Value = TextBox3.Text

            conn.Open()
            Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            rdr.Read()

            TextBox2.Text = rdr("Subject_Name").ToString()
            Label1.Text = rdr("Today_Date").ToString()
            Label2.Text = rdr("Count1").ToString()
            Label3.Text = rdr("Count2").ToString()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally 
            conn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```